# The constructor ServerSocket(int) is undefined

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am new at JAVA basically I do code in C++. Recently I needed to do something in JAVA socket programming. But I am getting a strange error in ServerSocket(..). I am trying to create a server socket in a particular port. For that my code is like below.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class ServerSocket {

    static ServerSocket socket1;
    protected final static int port = 19999;
    static Socket connection;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);

        }
        catch (IOException e) {}

    }

}
```

But I am getting compilation error "The constructor ServerSocket(int) is undefined". Thanks.

Comment: 1) That code won't compile as it's missing much and doesn't really make sense.. 2) Where's your class declaration for one? 3) When asking about compiler error messages, you'll always want to post the complete error message with your question.

Comment: Also, do you have your own class named `ServerSocket`? Again the error message would tell us much since it will give us the package-complete name of the erroneous class.

Comment: @Hovercraf, I did not post my whole code here. I just pasted the related code with ServerSocket class.

Comment: You don't appear to be posting enough so that we can fully understand what you might be doing wrong. Please post your [mcve] that shows your problem fully for us as well as (**again**) post your full error message(s). Let's avoid making us guess at answers.

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue. Problem was I named the class as ServerSocket. I just changed it to ServerSocketTest and its working. Like I said I am beginner at JAVA but not at OOP concept. Thanks everyone

Comment: Yep, it's as I suspected in my second comment above (and answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my second comment to your original question:

> Also, do you have your own class named ServerSocket?

You've named your class ServerSocket and so the Java compiler is looking for **the constructor in this class**, one that takes an int. Rename that class so you don't have a name conflict and now can use the Java core ServerSocket class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a java tutorial first. Just to learn the basic differences.

In short:

In Java everything has to be in a class. You define a static method named 'main'. This is the start of your application.

Here is your example (Filename: DemoClass.java):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DemoClass {

    private static ServerSocket socket1;
    private static final int port = 19999;

    private static void handleConnection(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        // Say hello
        out.write("Hello World\n".getBytes());
        out.flush();
        // Close the connection
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    // Use this exact method signature!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);
            // Here is some example what you could do
            Socket connection = socket1.accept();
            handleConnection(connection);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            // What should be done if this fails? E.g. port already in use
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I really suggest a Java and a Java Socket tutorial.

Greetings!

Answer (score -2):

The server program creates the *ServerSocket* object in a try-with-resources statement:

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*;

  class Test{

    private static ServerSocket socket1;
    private final static int port = 19999;
    public static void main (String [] args){
     try{
        socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);
     }
     catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

The *constructor* for *ServerSocket* throws an exception if it can't listen on the specified port. for example, the port is already being used.

Comment: Above answer copied without attribution from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html